# Where to put java serialization code

Tags: java, serialization

I have a number of objects that are serializable.
I am considering whether to place the actual serialization code in a separate utility class vs putting the serialization for each object into each object methods as a save/load methods.

Utility Class
pros : serialization all in one place can be tested all at once. Code works even when add new field to object.
cons : not very object oriented

Serialization methods in each object
pros : More Object Oriented
cons : for load need to explicitly change code if new field is added

Would anyone be able to give there thoughts on this. Mayby there is a best practice here that I can use ? 
Currently I have implemented/tested the utility class method

Frank.

Comment: do you have any reason not to use built-in java serialization and implement this mechanism yourself?

Comment: I would start with the built in serialization and only modify it if you really needed it.

Comment: Hi Guys, Sorry I wasn't clear I am using built in java serialization. My question is really more whether to have the serialization code i.e. readObject and writeObject as a separate class or put it into each class to be serialized. Hope it is clearer now

Comment: So whether to have class SerializationUtils { myObj loadObject(); void saveObject(myObj) OR class myObj { void loadObject(); void saveObject()}; for each object myObject. Theres about 5 or 6 myObj classes. I hope this makes my choice clearer

Comment: We decided to put the methods that do the serialization into the objects because this was more object oriented so each object has a loadObject and saveObject method. Mayby the question is not good because there is no clear right or wrong answer. Is this the wrong forum to ask about design decisions. Seems to be.